# Performing calculations using filters within a Gmail account

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is it possible to perform calculations using filters within a Gmail account?

I've received receipts for various tickets, and I want to calculate the number of people who paid a certain amount of money.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Gmail filters don't offer much customization or flexibility. I don't think you will be able to run some calculation with your filters.

Yet, you can use `Gmail Stats` to perform some calculations on your Gmail inbox. See [Google System article](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/09/gmail-stats.html) on this issue.

Comment: btw, that linked blog is an unofficial blog

Comment: Hmm, installed the addon, keeps failing with the error that I need to install this iGoogle widget. I've installed it 3 times already + checked it had installed properly.